# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib

Tags: macos, terminal, fortran, gfortran, dyld

I am trying to learn Fortran programming language, as a test I wrote a simple program like this:

```
!Fortran Program
program first
print *, "Hello World"
end program first
```

Then I threw this code file in to mac terminal and run `gfortran first.f95` which then gave me an output of `a.out` as expected.
However, when I try to run the output in terminal by navigating into the output directory and typing `./a.out`. It gave me this error output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/liang/Desktop/Programs/Fortran/Test/a.out
  Reason: image not found
```

`liang` is my username.

Comment: Hm, it sounds like there is something wrong with your installation. How have you installed gfortran?

Comment: @Ross I have a bunch of programming softwares on my computer so I’m not entirely sure but I think it is Anaconda.

Comment: You need the correct version of gfortran as well. If you are still interested in thism try to search for "libgofrtran" among the files in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my problem was caused because the library was not in default path and instead "anaconda" got in the path so that's why the compiler could not load it. I am a pure amateur user so I may explain not accurate in terms of technical words.

What I did was, I uninstalled my anaconda and deleted the folder in my Mac. Installed gcc "brew install gcc" again,  and it worked! and then after, I installed my anaconda again, so now everything seemingly is ok.

Answer (score 0):

#### My situation

I am also just learning, and I had a similar error message after compiling MUMPS library (http://mumps-solver.org).

I compiled the sequential version of MUMPS manually after brew installing the dependencies. When I ran the test examples, I got the same error message that libgfortran.3.dylib could not be loaded.

My brew gnu compiler is gcc version 9 and it is invoked by gcc-9, g++-9 and gfortran-9 (for C, C++ and Fortran respectively). Meanwhile gcc, g++ and gfortran invoke the compilers installed by anaconda.

#### How I solve it

I recompiled MUMPS using gcc-9 and gfortran-9 instead of gcc-9 and gfortran, and now everything works.